# Can't run meshlabserver filters on a headless virtual environment

Tags: meshlab

I have meshlab installed on debian 9.4 using `sudo apt-get install meshlab`

first when trying to dump on the filters list

```
sudo xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 800x600x24" meshlabserver -d filters
```

it fails with this log

```
Loading Plugins:
Current Plugins Dir is: /usr/lib/meshlab/plugins 
Error in XMLFile: filter_measure.xml - line: -1, column: -1 - 
Error in XMLFile: filter_mutualinfo.xml - line: -1, column: -1 - 
Total 227 filtering actions
Total 13 io plugins
called here! 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

and when trying to run a filter

```
sudo xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 800x600x24" meshlabserver -i original.obj -s /usr/lib/meshlab/plugins/filter_measure.xml
```

it fails and shows this log

```
script /usr/lib/meshlab/plugins/filter_measure.xml
Loading Plugins:
Current Plugins Dir is: /usr/lib/meshlab/plugins 
Error in XMLFile: filter_measure.xml - line: -1, column: -1 - 
Error in XMLFile: filter_mutualinfo.xml - line: -1, column: -1 - 
Total 227 filtering actions
Total 13 io plugins
Opening a file with extention obj
Mesh original.obj loaded has 22296 vn 7432 fn
Apply FilterScript: '/usr/lib/meshlab/plugins/filter_measure.xml'
Failure in parsing script /usr/lib/meshlab/plugins/filter_measure.xml
No root node with name FilterScript
Current rootname is MESHLAB_FILTER_INTERFACE
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you install meshlab?

Comment: @TarunLalwani sudo apt-get install meshlab

Comment: Try inspecting file `/usr/lib/meshlab/plugins/filter_measure.xml` as it could be broken or empty.

Comment: Hi @EvanLévesque, I was able to reproduce the Segmentation fault error when running with sudo, but when running with my current user it was fine, come to think of it, it may have something to do with X as my current user is running in xfce under mint.  I'm assuming you are in a ssh terminal session into a remote server? do you have an environment where you have desktop? and what happens when you run it without `xvfb-run`? just run it with `meshlabserver -i original.obj -s /usr/lib/meshlab/plugins/filter_measure.xml`?

Comment: Hi @runwuf correct, I am running meshlab on a google cloud compute engine debian vm where SSH connection is the only way to go. running it without `xvfb` will through 'cannot connect to X server' error

Comment: @EvanLévesque, it looks trying to run meshlabserver in headless mode is a longshot...  see the comments here:
"There are some filters using renering context & GPU (e.g. Ambient Occlusion), that were neeed as batch-able operations. This is why we had to include a rendering context in the initialization of MeshLabServer.

We do not have an "official" workaround for this."
(https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/issues/78)

Comment: @runwuf that's a valid answer

Comment: @EvanLévesque - sorry probably not the answer you were looking for to solve your problem though... I just edited my original post if you would accept the answer :-)

Comment: @EvanLévesque - Thanks for accepting the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like trying to run meshlabserver in headless mode is a longshot... see the comments here: "There are some filters using [an OpenGL] rendering context & GPU (e.g. Ambient Occlusion), that were needed as batch-able operations. This is why we had to include a rendering context in the initialization of MeshLabServer. We do not have an 'official' workaround for this."

(Source: https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/issues/78)

I think your best chance is to run this with X instead of trying to get it working in headless mode with xvfb-run...

Comment: One would think that if an application has "server" in its name it should be able to run on a server environment.